# Flask variable doesn't work for console.log

Tags: flask

I am trying to pass a variable from Flask to my `console.log()` but it doesn't seem to work.

````
<html>
<head>
    <title>Flask Shop</title>
</head>
<body>
<p>{{ message }}</p>
<style>
    body {
        padding: 20px;
        background-color: #1d1f21;
        font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    }

    h3 {
        color: red;
        margin: 0;
        pading: 0;
    }

    p {
        color: #f3a683;
        font-weight: bold;
        margin: 0;
        pading: 0;
    }
</style>
</body>
<script>
    console.log({{ variable }})
</script>
</html>```
````

Flask

```
@app.route("/")
def hello():
    variable = "test"
    message = "test"
    return render_template('index.html', message=message, variable=variable)
```

The `<p>{{ message }}</p>` works perfectly, just not `{{ variable }}` However this should work right? Passing a variable with `{{ var }}` should work anywhere in the HTML file.

Comment: Use quotes around ``{{ variable }}`` in ``console.log``, otherwise it will be interpreted by javascript as a variable name (and not a string).

Answer (score 0):

@guimauve answered it with:

> Use quotes around {{ variable }} in console.log, otherwise it will be interpreted by javascript as a variable name (and not a string)